# DOM Camel integration with Websphere Commerce

Tags: apache-camel, websphere-commerce

We have integrated Websphere to support Camel integration and we have set up the DOM inventory model. So when the user reaches the product page and selects an item, an external call is made to Camel integration framework and it updates INVAVL table of Commerce.

However in page, the inventory status is still shown as unavailable. But, if the same product is chosen again, it is showing as available because the second request is made to the database directly instead of Camel request.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When Commerce calls the external system, it returns the object as returned by the external system, rather than what it stored in its caches.

This gives some discrepancies in behaviour, if the external system does not provide the full information set, that commerce itself applies to an inventory response.

Why it does this, is not really clear to me, but I have observed it to be true. It also affects physical store inventory display, as the external system will populate the external identifier of the inventory record, while the cache-only version wont. And the jsps expect it to be there.

So first run, will look ok, but subsequent executions will show no inventory.

The easiest way to debug this, is to use Soap UI to call GetInventoryAvailability on WCS both when

a) No existing cache entry is present
and
b) When an existing cache entry is present.

Then fiddle with the camel response, until it matches the response returned in b).

Typically, its fields you weren't thinking were important such as StoreIdentifier and  AvailabilityTime.